# Opening a jar file in a new terminal from existing java gui program

Tags: java, jar, terminal, execute

I have a Java GUI program, I want to run another jar file in a new terminal (which does not have a GUI) from this program whenever the user clicks a specified button. Can someone suggest how can I do this?

Comment: Does this create another jvm to run that jar file?

Comment: It would almost have to, unless the terminal window is hosting a terminal emulator program communicating back by pipes or sockets.  At any rate, the answer depends on the host operating and windowing systems and preferred terminal window program.

Comment: yes, it does, I mean it should

Comment: I tried something with ProcessBuilder but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What is the motivation for running the another jar in terminal window. Do you want just run the jar? Does it have to be in (another) terminal? Does it have to be in another process for some reason? Will the separate JAR program take any input? What kind of terminal capabilities will it require?

Comment: yes, it has to be another terminal and it will require input and user interaction. I was trying to just open it through an emulator like xterm using ProcessBuilder but when I package my original file, the xterm thing doesnot work any more.. seems like i need something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting new terminal requires spawn new process using ProcessBuilder or System.exec. And this depends on operating system and its configuration. In linux xterm running standalone jar file is started like this:

```
 File dir = new File("/directory/to/the/jar/file");
    String jarName ="standalone.jar";
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/xterm","-e","java -jar "+jarName);
    processBuilder.directory(dir);
    processBuilder.start();
```

If there is no standalone jar, then class path has to be spesified using -cp -parameter to the java excutable...

Alternative might be just run the given jar using separated ClassLoader and redirecting System.out and System.in. This requires writing some kind of GUI for the running jar. If only the output of the process is required and no terminal emulation is required this is not hard. Just redirecting System.out to some textarea. If there are more requirements for the input / output for the running then it might be possible to use terminal emulator written in java to do these things for you.